# zookeeper Supervisor returned FATAL. Please check the role log file, stderr, or stdout

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I try to run zookeeper, but I have an error :Failed to start role.

```
at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.restore(FileTxnSnapLog.java:196)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase.loadDataBase(ZKDatabase.java:223)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.loadDataBase(QuorumPeer.java:417)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.start(QuorumPeer.java:409)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.runFromConfig(QuorumPeerMain.java:156)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:116)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:79)
2016-03-01 10:55:38,873 ERROR org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain: Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to run quorum server 
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.loadDataBase(QuorumPeer.java:454)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.start(QuorumPeer.java:409)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.runFromConfig(QuorumPeerMain.java:156)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:116)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:79)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/zookeeper/version-2/log.d00015690 (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog$FileTxnIterator.createInputArchive(FileTxnLog.java:574)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog$FileTxnIterator.goToNextLog(FileTxnLog.java:543)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnLog$FileTxnIterator.next(FileTxnLog.java:625)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.restore(FileTxnSnapLog.java:196)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase.loadDataBase(ZKDatabase.java:223)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeer.loadDataBase(QuorumPeer.java:417)
```

any help please !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have premission to open this file, have you tried running zookeeper as root/sudo?

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/zookeeper/version-2/log.d00015690 (Permission denied)
```

Comment: yes I try, but the same problem.(Permission denied)

Comment: Do you have other log-files in that directory? Can you read that file manually? What happens if you move it or create a new one?

Comment: yes I have many other file like log.d00000001 log.a0000001etc.